# catkin_make install

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-install, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does catkin_make install do. And should I run catkin_make install after catkn_make every time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259788/catkin_make-install/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin_make install` is described here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace#Installing_Packages

It is used to produce an "installed" version of one or more packages. When you are developing, you can use the `devel` space, so you do not need to run it every time. `install` is used when you are going to distribute your package for others to use, especially if you plan on creating binary packages. If your package is solely for you to use, then you can ignore `install` and probably be happy. If you want others to use your package, you should add installation directives to your `CMakeLists.txt` files and ensure that `catkin_make install` produces a correct install space. This will allow others to actually install your package to their system rather than having to clone the source into every workspace they want to use it in.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-04-20**:
Thanks for the explanation.